# changing the default audio stream controlled by volume buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-audiomanager

I am sorry about the question title but I am not sure what this particular android feature is called
This is a screenshot of my app when I press the volume button
[image]
We can see that the telephone symbol is on the top, which means means it is the one whose volume gets controlled by the volume buttons
However I am testing this on a  tablet (not a phone) so changing this volume has no effect on the speaker output
What I want to do is map the volume buttons to the 2nd speaker icon shown here, which changes the speaker output volume
How do I set the tablet's volume button to map to this output stream (or whatever this feature is called)?
I have tried
`am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);`
and
`am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);`
where am is an `Audiomanager`, but both seem to have the same output

Answer (score 2):

The `Activity` class has a [`setVolumeControlStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29) method:

> Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by the hardware volume controls.

Call it with the stream type you want the hardware buttons to modify the volume for while your app is in the foreground (e.g. `STREAM_MUSIC`), and then call it with `USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE` when you want to reset the behaviour to the default.

By the way, the speaker icon does not represent the volume for the loudspeaker. At least the last time I checked, it represented the media volume (that is, all streams that follow the media routing strategy, e.g. `STREAM_MUSIC`).

Comment: This should be called in onCreate()? If this is what controls the volume then what is the use of AudioManager?

Comment: so I should call it with `v` at onCreate() or onResume() and then call it with `USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE` at onPause()?

Comment: I used `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` in `onCreate()` and `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);` in `onResume()` but it's still doing the same thing

Comment: `onResume` [is called after](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) `onCreate` when you launch an activity. You should place the call to `setVolumeControlStream(USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE)` so that it's called when you no longer want to override which volume gets modified.

Comment: As for the purpose of the `AudioManager`; it's used (mainly) for getting and setting system-wide audio settings. The behavior override set with `setVolumeControlStream` is Activity-specific.

Comment: Sorry I made some mistake. This is what I have done: `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` in onResume(), and then next time in onCreate();; `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);` in onPause(). But it's still doing the same thing, that is, the hardware buttons control the volume stream represented by the telephone symbol. I want it to control the stream represented by he speaker symbol.

Comment: @Michael, can i get your full name or email plz.

Comment: StackOverflow has a chat service if there's something you want to ask that can't be covered in a regular question/comment.

Comment: Ivent use chat service, how to find u in chat, sorry for this